# Possible if/elif statement bug

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

OK Guys I swear I'm not stupid, but I have come across the strangest thing while coding a backdoor server/client script.

This is an example/simplified script that works exactly how I'd expect it to:

```
    command = input(str("Command >>>"))
    if command == '1':
        print("1")
    elif command == '2':
        print("2")
    elif command == '3':
        print("3")
    elif command == '4':
        print("4")
    else:
        print("Not a command")
```

Pretty simple, right?
Now usually I'd just use an example script, but I am about to slam my head into a table, so here's a section of the real script:

```
while 1:
    print("")
    command = input(str("Command >> "))
    if command == "view_cwd":
        conn.send(command.encode())
        print("")
        print("Command sent, waiting for execution... ")
        print("")
        files = conn.recv(5000)
        files = files.decode()
        print("Command Output: ", files)

    elif command == "quit":
        quit()

    elif command == "download_file":
        conn.send(command.encode())
        filepath = input(str("Please enter filename and path: "))
        conn.send(filepath.encode())
        file = conn.recv(100000)
        filename = input(str(Enter preferred filename: ))
        new_file = open(filename, 'wb')
        new_file.write(file)new_file.close()
        print(filename, "has been downloaded")

    elif command == "custom_dir":
        conn.send(command.encode())
        print("")
        user_input = input(str("Custom Dir: "))
        conn.send(user_input.encode())
        print("")
        print("Command has been sent")
        print("")
        files = conn.recv(5000)
        files = files.decode()
        print("Custom DIR result: ", files)

    else:
        print("")
        print("Command not recognized")
```

Still looks pretty standard right? Now here's the bizarre part: The 'view_cwd' 'quit' and 'custom_dir' commands work fine and execute, but if I enter 'download_file', I get this output:

```
Command >> download_file

Command not recognized

Command >>
```

That's an error code I made, but I can see absolutely no reason why the other elif/if statements work, but not this one. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: a couple of small errors in the code :filename = input(str(Enter preferred filename: )) needs quotation marks around the string "Enter preferred filename:" and you need a line break between the newfile.write and newfile.close statements. With those corrections, I don't get the same problem you describe - can't reproduce the error.

Comment: @Stidgeon thank you for the small code corrections, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: does your input match `download_file` are there any leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: No, I've tried this 10 something times for that exact reason. It's correct. I also created an extra command called 'test' and just told it to print 'test', but it didn't work either. I am genuinely so confused, that such a simple program could have an issue like this. It's basic python!